# How do I emulate a "wrapper script" on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, dos

On Linux, when I want to prepare the environment of a program before starting it, I'm using a wrapper script:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=...
 cd /some/folder
 exec ./tool "$@"
```

How would I do the last line, especially the `"$@"`, on Windows?

Note: I'm wrapping commands which take a lot of arguments (like `java` or `mvn`), so I need a solution which works for > 10 arguments.

Being able to `exec` would be nice but is only a minor concern.

Comment: `%*` gets all parameters. See `call /?` for more infos. Not sure, if that helps; batch is not as smart as linux. For `exec` see, if `start` helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
set JAVA_HOME=...
cd ...
start "" .\sometool %*
endlocal
```

Setlocal localizes environment changes to the script (see `setlocal /?` for details), and `%*` means 'all script parameters'. The `start` command is a cmd.exe command that spawns an executable.

The `start` command has odd parsing rules; the first quoted string on its command line is considered to be a console window title, which is superfluous if you are not spawning a console window. This means that a command like this won't work as expected:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe"
```

If you run this command, you will spawn a new instance of cmd.exe with the quoted string as its console window title, which is clearly not what was intended. Instead, you have to write this:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\excel.exe"
```